# Grouping a column as list in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have data in the form ("name","id"), where one name can have multiple ids. I wish to convert it to a List or Set so that i have a list of ids corresponding to each name and the "name" becomes a unique field.
I tried the following but it seems to be wrong:

```
val group = dataFrame.map( r => (dataFrame.rdd.filter(s => s.getAs(0) == r.getAs(0)).collect()))
```

I get the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

What is the solution to this, does groupBy work here, if yes how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is your `DataFrame`:

```
val df = Seq(("dave",1),("dave",2),("griffin",3),("griffin",4)).toDF("name","id")
```

You can then do:

```
df.groupBy(col("name")).agg(collect_list(col("id")) as "ids")
```

Comment: Another question, what if I have another column (say 'place') with one to one mapping with 'name', then how do i aggregate. Should i do the same thing and then do a join or is there a way to specify here that 'place' column has to be taken as it is?